# Extending the py.test fixture parameters

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

Is it possible to extend the parameters used in a [py.test fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html)?

For example, I would use this code to generate a simple fixture to return the letters `a`, `b` and `c`.

```
@pytest.fixture(params=['a', 'b', 'c'])
    def first_three_letters(self, request):
        return request.param
```

However, if I then wanted to extend for another three letters - i.e. `d`, `e` and `f` – I'm currently creating a brand new fixture

```
@pytest.fixture(params=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
    def first_six_letters(self, request):
        return request.param
```

This feels like it doesn't correspond to the DRY principle. Is there a way to use py.test fixtures in an extensible way?

I could use parameters on the test directly, but there are a lot of tests for both fixtures, so there would be many repeated lines containing `@pytest.mark.parametrize`, so that feels even less DRY.

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer

Not yet.

#### Long answer

If the parameter lists are always static, they could be composed as constants and passed as params:

```
LETTERS = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

@pytest.fixture(params=LETTERS[:3])
def first_three_letters(self, request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=LETTERS)
def first_six_letters(self, request):
    return request.param
```

However, if the params are not known before calling `pytest.fixture()`, there is no simple solution. However, a [there is a proposal](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/proposals/parametrize_with_fixtures.html) allowing a fixture to "yield from" other fixtures. Here's how it would look:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=['a', 'b', 'c'])
def first_three_letters(request):
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=['d', 'e', 'f'])
def second_three_letters(request):
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=[
    pytest.fixture_request('first_three_letters'),
    pytest.fixture_request('second_three_letters'),
])
def first_six_letters(request):
    return request.param
```